# Bootstrap stacked nav width issue when collapsing

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, nav

When the items are toggled to collapse they collapse side by side in the `col-sm-2` class. Click the "Challenge Management" to see what It's doing.

I want "Challenge Management" to either take up 100% of the `container` or always have it stack properly.

Any thoughts? I'm missing something simple.

https://jsfiddle.net/egfs8t61/

```
<div class="col-sm-2" style="position:fixed;right: 0;left: 0;z-index: 1030; max-height:100%; overflow-y:auto; margin-top:-67px;padding-top:67px;">
  <a href="#" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" data-target="#menu_ChallengeManagement" class="collapsed">
    <strong> Challenge Management </strong>
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></i>
  </a>
  <ul class="nav nav-stacked ui-sortable collapse" id="menu_ChallengeManagement" aria-expanded="false" style="height: 0px;">
    <li class="ui-sortable-handle" id="li_86">
      <a href="#" onclick="changeIframe('/challenge/entry', '')">
        <i class="glyphicon "></i> New Entry
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="ui-sortable-handle" id="li_87">
      <a href="#" onclick="changeIframe('/challenge/list', '')">
        <i class="glyphicon "></i> My Tasks <span class="badge badge-info MyTaskscount"></span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="ui-sortable-handle" id="li_88">
      <a href="#" onclick="changeIframe('/challenge/history', '')">
        <i class="glyphicon "></i> My Entries
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <a href="#" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="true" data-target="#menu_Fabrication" class="">
    <strong> Fabrication </strong>
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i>
  </a>
  <ul class="nav nav-stacked ui-sortable collapse in" id="menu_Fabrication" aria-expanded="true">
    <li class="ui-sortable-handle" id="li_79">
      <a href="#" onclick="changeIframe('/fms/index', '')">
        <i class="glyphicon "></i> Fab Management (FMS)
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="ui-sortable-handle" id="li_80">
      <a href="#" onclick="changeIframe('/que/departmentstatus', 'Org=&amp;Page=1')">
        <i class="glyphicon "></i> Department Status
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="ui-sortable-handle" id="li_85">
      <a href="#" onclick="changeIframe('/schedule/taktmgr', '')">
        <i class="glyphicon "></i> Takt Manager
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not understand your question completely. But is this what you looking for?

[Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/egfs8t61/1/)

```
 <div class="col-sm-2" style="position:fixed;right: 0;left: 0;z-index: 1030; max-height:100%; overflow-y:auto; margin-top:-67px;padding-top:67px;">
  <a href="#" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" data-target="#menu_ChallengeManagement" class="collapsed">
    <strong> Challenge Management </strong>
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></i>
  </a>
  <ul class="nav nav-stacked ui-sortable collapse" id="menu_ChallengeManagement" aria-expanded="false" style="height: 0px;">
    <li class="ui-sortable-handle" id="li_86">
      <a href="#" onclick="changeIframe('/challenge/entry', '')">
        <i class="glyphicon "></i> New Entry
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="ui-sortable-handle" id="li_87">
      <a href="#" onclick="changeIframe('/challenge/list', '')">
        <i class="glyphicon "></i> My Tasks <span class="badge badge-info MyTaskscount"></span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="ui-sortable-handle" id="li_88">
      <a href="#" onclick="changeIframe('/challenge/history', '')">
        <i class="glyphicon "></i> My Entries
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <br>
  <a href="#" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" data-target="#menu_Fabrication" class="collapsed">
    <strong> Fabrication </strong>
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i>
  </a>
  <ul class="nav nav-stacked ui-sortable collapse" id="menu_Fabrication" aria-expanded="true">
    <li class="ui-sortable-handle" id="li_86">
      <a href="#" onclick="changeIframe('/fms/index', '')">
        <i class="glyphicon "></i> Fab Management (FMS)
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="ui-sortable-handle" id="li_87">
      <a href="#" onclick="changeIframe('/que/departmentstatus', 'Org=&amp;Page=1')">
        <i class="glyphicon "></i> Department Status
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="ui-sortable-handle" id="li_88">
      <a href="#" onclick="changeIframe('/schedule/taktmgr', '')">
        <i class="glyphicon "></i> Takt Manager
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I am going to blame this on a late Friday brain spasm. Yes I was looking for what the <br> did... but for some reason I assumed I 'had' to be doing something wrong in the CSS. Thanks for your time.